# I can no longer search within urls in chat

Tags: bug, chat, search

[This](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=imgur&Room=35&User=11935&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=stars) search used to be a handy way of seeing images I had posted, but it seems that the search algorithm has been updated to exclude searching within URLs. Can this be fixed?

Comment: Interestingly [this search (i.imgur.com)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=i.imgur.com&Room=35&User=11935&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=stars) still works.

Comment: Looks like you need full url, [this also works](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fimgur.com&user=11935&room=35). So probably no bug here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Even if it's not *strictly* a bug it's [broken my workflow](http://xkcd.com/1172/).

Comment: Nah, breaking changes are part of SE. Remember the envelope! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the search backend has indeed changed, from SQL Server Full Text Search to elasticsearch. Since it seems to work fine with a longer url link (comments), I'm not sure this is something that needs additional effort to reinstate *exactly* the old behaviour.

Comment: I still can't seem to find a search term that will return `*.imgur.com` (the `*` operator does not work in this case). Terms seem to all be required, and it doesn't look like I can `OR`. Any suggestions?